# How to disable the interactive preview for substitute in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, substitute

In Neovim, when I type `:%s/foo` then the current buffer changes to have all instances of `foo` removed, basically giving a preview of the change. Coming from standard Vim, I find this confusing and it's also very slow for large files. How can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `:h inccommand` to an empty string.

```
let &inccommand = ""
```

From `:h inccommand`:

> When nonempty, `inccommand`, shows the effects of `:substitute`, `:smagic`, `:snomagic` and user commands with the `:command-preview` flag as you type.

Comment: Great, thanks! I noticed another very related issue and thought you might have an idea (otherwise I'll start a new question)? When I type `/foo` it nicely highlights all matches and doesn't change the scroll position but when I do `:%s/foo` then it scrolls to the first match even while I'm still typing. Is there a way to instead scroll to the next match (just like `/foo`)?

Comment: First: the reason any search (including substitute) command scrolls is because of `:h incsearch`. If you search for a word which is outside the current view of the window, it *will* scroll. Second: the reason `%s/foo` scrolls differently from `/foo` is because you are matching from the beginning of the file, not from current line downward. The behavior you're asking for can be achieved with `:,,$s/foo` (see `:h :range`). But that would of course only substitute from the current line to the last line; not the whole buffer. If you think about it, it makes sense.